# Why does specifing a named parameter change the parameters type

Tags: ruby

I recently ran into this and am curious if I am using named parameters incorrectly or to better understand why they behave this way.

```
def test_param(b=false)
    if b
        puts 'param is true'
        puts b
        puts b.class
    else
        puts 'param is false'
        puts b
        puts b.class
    end
end
```

when I test this function in a REPL I am seeing

```
2.5.3 :213 > test_param(true)
param is true
true
TrueClass
 => nil
2.5.3 :214 > test_param(false)
param is false
false
FalseClass
 => nil
2.5.3 :215 > test_param(b:true)
param is true
{:b=>true}
Hash
 => nil
2.5.3 :216 > test_param(b:false)
param is true
{:b=>false}
Hash
 => nil
2.5.3 :217 >
```

How come when I use a named parameter the variable data type is changed to a Hash, this *seems* wrong.

Comment: When you haven't specified all the parameters yet, something like `any_method(a: 1, b: 2)` is interpreted as `any_method({ a: 1, b: 2 })`, on ruby 2, it counts as keyword arguments only after the mandatory parameters, ruby 3, it counts after all the parameters, I know that because [I asked it some months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807929/argumenterror-with-optional-parameters), so in your case, is not a "keyword argument conversion", you are just passing a Hash

Comment: @saviu-u thats not correct. In Ruby 3 `any_method({ a: 1, b: 2 })` will always be treated as a positional argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike in other languages (such as Python), Ruby strictly separates positional arguments and keyword arguments. You can't provide a keyword parameter as a positional argument when calling a method and vice-versa.

In your case, you have define a single positional parameter in your method (namely `b`). In your last two examples, you are passing a Hash to it. Note that the curly braces you generally use to define a hash are optional when calling methods and passing a Hash as its last argument. In older Ruby versions, this was used as a convention to allow/pass an optional list of arguments which works similar to keyword arguments.

As a Hash object is always truthy (remember that only `false` and `nil` are falsey in Ruby), you are always using the `if` branch of your conditional and outputting the information you see there.

With that being said, if you want to accept keyword arguments with your method, you have to define it accordingly, e.g.:

```
def test_param(b: false)
  # ...
end
```

Note the difference in the parameter definition here. You can learn more about keyword arguments in Ruby from [the Ruby language documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments).

Comment: It should be noted though that in Ruby 2 `test_param({ b: false })`  would be converted into keyword parameters. Strict separation was only really added in Ruby 3.

Comment: This was deprecated in Ruby 2.7 and enforced in 3.0, yes. That's mainly what I alluded to with "older Ruby versions" in my answer, while trying to avoid giving too many overwhelming details. Regardless of this, you would still have to define the method to accept keyword arguments even in Ruby 2.